# Getting Javascript variable from a source script on an html page loaded in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Following up from this question here: [Accessing JavaScript variable in an iframe, from the parent window on same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366841/accessing-javascript-variable-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-window-on-same-domai)

For purposes of posting something testable here, I have a src.js file set up like:

```
var foo = {"foo":"bar"};
```

then I can an HTML page test1.html with this line in the head:

```
<script src="src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I have another HTML page test2.html, with

```
<iframe src="test1.html"></iframe>
```

How can I access foo from test2.html? I tried the following but could not find `foo` (running this on button click from a div in test2.html)

```
  console.log("foo: " + typeof foo);
  console.log("foo: " + window.foo);
  console.log("Frame window: " + window.frames[0].window); //this works
  console.log("Sections: " + window.frames[0].window.foo);
```

Note: In the iframe, `foo` is definitely there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what eventually worked for me. In JS library:

```
const foo = {"foo":"bar"};

window.getFoo = function() {
  return foo;
}
```

On page with iFrame (test2.html):

```
  var iframe = document.getElementById("mainPanel"); //mainPanel is the id of the iframe
  var iWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
  var foo = iWindow.getFoo();
```